# SwiftUI observe list's content size dynamically

Tags: swiftui

How can I dynamically observe the content's height (including the height of non visible items) of a SwiftUI List when items are added or removed from it?

---

Long story:

I'm building a SwiftUI app inside a macOS popover.

My layout should respect these rules:

1. The maximum popover height should be 500
2. The popover height should fit the list content size when the list isn't too big, in other words, the popover shouldn't be unnecessary higher than the list height + header + footer (no empty space)
3. The popover height should re-scale every time the list height changes (e.g.: adding an item, removing an item)

Example 1: when the list size is short and therefore not scrollable, the popover height should be 300.

```
\ /
-----------------------
|       header        |  50
|                     |
|---------------------|
|        list         |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |  200
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|---------------------|
|       footer        |  50
|                     |
-----------------------
```

Example 2: when the list size is long, the list is scrollable, the popover height should be equal to its max (500).

```
\ /
-----------------------
|       header        |  50
|                     |
|---------------------|
|        list         |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |  400
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     | 
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|---------------------         Not shown: (scrollable)
                            |- - - - - - - - - - - 
                            |  more list content  |
                            |                     |
                            |                     |
                            |                     |
                            |--------------------- 
|---------------------|
|       footer        |  50
|                     |
-----------------------
```

I'm not able to calculate the popover's height based on the list's dynamic content.

Comment: Can you show a code to reproduce the issue? Also before calculating the absolute size (which usually indicates a workaround for inability to properly use a dynamic sizing), did you try to use normal methods like `maxHeight` and `presentationCompactAdaptation`?